# Using a Map or Dictionary in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, dictionary, lodash

I want to use a Dictionary or a Map structure in TypeScript to have the ability to iterate through the collection as well as having direct access `myMap['key']`.

Right now I'm using the `lodash` interface `Map<K, V>`. As long as I use the interface just for function parameters it's working fine. Initiailzing a this map from JavaScript is also not an issue. But I have no idea how to initialize this data structure within TypeScript.

What I have:

**TypeScript Lib**

```
static async showAjaxModal(modalId: string, url: string, method: string, body?: string, actions?: Map<string, (e) => {}>) {
    ...

    // Bind events
    if (actions) {
        _.forEach(actions, (value: (e) => {}, key: string) => {
            $(`#${modalId}`).on('click', `#${key}`, value);
        });
    }

    ...
}
```

**JavaScript Call:**

```
eMedia.Modal.showAjaxModal(
    'demo-modal-ajax',
    '/modaldemo',
    'get',
     null,
    {
            ['buttonOkId']: e => { alert('ok'); },
            ['buttonCancelId']: e => { alert('close'); 
    }
});
```

In TypeScript I have two constants `const defaultOkButtonId = 'buttonOkId'` and `const defaultCancelButtonId = 'buttonCancelId'`. How can I construct the above data scructure in TypeScript while using the constants as key name?

I guess the solution is very obviouse, but I'm stuck.

Comment: Any particular reason for using Lodash's `Map` instead of the standard runtime's `Map`? (It was added in ES2015 and is entirely polyfillable if you need to support obsolete browsers like IE11.) Or for that use case, really, an object rather than a `Map` makes sense.

Comment: Using the standard runtime `Map` is even better. But how to force the TS compiler to use this? I have other libraries around which make use of lodash. My editor as well as the compiler do always indicate an error as soon as I use the `Map` because I do not follow the lodash signature. Is there a way in the standard runtime version to make the key/value type-safe?